# Get Connection String through Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I am developing a blazor application. I want to have connection string and some other key in a class as service.

For that I have created an interface

```
interface IDbConnector
{
    string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    bool SomeKey { get; set; }
}
```

and in my class I want to have something like that

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    public class DbConnector : IDbConnector
    {
        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public DbConnector(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public string ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString();

        public bool SomeKey = Configuration.GetSection("xyz");
    }
```

I can register it as a service with

```
services.AddScoped<IDbConnector, DbConnector>();
```

But inside DbConnector class it says

> A fiels initializer can not refrence the non static field ,method or
>   property DbConnector.Configuration

Pardon for my coding pattern as I am new to DI concept. Please suggest if there is another and better way to do this.

Comment: You can do `ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString();` in your constructor.

Comment: @JohanP , Error: ConnectionString  does not exist in current context

Comment: You need to declare it. `public string ConnectionString {get;set;}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure connection string from controller (ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490808/configure-connection-string-from-controller-asp-net-core-mvc-2-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a syntax error, these should be expression bodied property accessors. `=` to `=>`

```
public string ConnectionString => Configuration.GetConnectionString();

public bool SomeKey => Configuration.GetSection("xyz");
```

Instead you've tried to initialise them as fields. Fields initialise pre-constructor, therefore cannot access the configuration.

Answer (score -1):

```
      services.AddConfiguration()  // enable Configuration Services

       var config = new WeblogConfiguration();
       Configuration.Bind("Weblog", config);      //  <--- This
       services.AddSingleton(config);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.