# Change dbContext connection string from Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection, dbcontext

I am trying to pass connection string to my DBContext in Asp.Net MVC and it worked when I pass a static variable to it. But my requirement is to pass the connection string from session variable.

***Multiple user will have their their own database, therefore we store
 their connection string in Session.***

**How can I use Session to store connection string in HttpContext.Session and change connection string of DBContext by Per Request?**

> DB Context

```
 public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }
```

> Session variable

```
var session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ConnectionString");
```

Comment: it sounds like you need middleware which check session and create new instance of dbContext

Comment: And its not per query but per request.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788272/how-to-instantiate-a-dbcontext-in-ef-core

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I dynamically generate my connection string using the following code (trimmed down a little):

```
public partial class MastersContext : BaseContext
{
    public MastersContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString, typeof(MastersContext), "Entities.Masters.MastersEF")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Materials> Materials { get; set; }
}

public class BaseContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public BaseContext(string connectionString, Type contextType, string connectionMetadata)
                    : base(GetEntityConnectionString(connectionString,
                                                     contextType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name,
                                                     connectionMetadata))
    {
        this.Initialise();
    }
}

public static string GetEntityConnectionString(string connectionString, string contextTypeName, string connectionMetadata)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder //(System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder)
    {
        Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
        ProviderConnectionString = connectionString,
        Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}/{1}.csdl|res://{0}/{1}.ssdl|res://{0}/{1}.msl", contextTypeName, connectionMetadata)
    };

    result = entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString();

    return result;
}
```