# Create user using C# ASP.NET MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Im beginner to ASP.Net MVC and I have faced some difficulties while creating new user, using Asp.Net Identity.

***The non-generic-type 'UserStore' cannot be used with type-argument***

The code that I have done is given below.

CreateNewUser method

```
public static bool CreateNewUser()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            //var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
            UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            string password = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 4);
            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.Email = "test@gmail.com";
            user.UserName = "test@gmail.com";

            string userPWD = password;

            var result = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

            return true;
        }
```

Here is my classes,

Role  class

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int, UserRole>
    {
        public Role() { }
        public Role(string name) { Name = name; }

    }
```

UserClaim  class

```
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
    {
    }
```

UserLogin  class

```
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
    {
    }
```

UserRole  class

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
    {
    }
```

ApplicationUser  class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
    {
        public DateTime? ActiveUntil;


        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

    }
```

RoleStore  class

```
public class RoleStore : RoleStore<Role, int, UserRole>
    {
        public RoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
```

UserStore  class

```
public class UserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, int,
        UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
    {
        public UserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
```

ApplicationSignInManager  class

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
```

ApplicationUserManager  class

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
            : base(store)
        {
            PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 8,
                // RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            //manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            //manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, int,
        UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
           : base("name=AppConnection")
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class IdentityConfig
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new ApplicationDbContext());
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            //app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<Role>>((options, context) =>
            //    new RoleManager<Role>(
            //        new RoleStore<Role>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())));

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
            });
        }
    }
```

Can anyone lead me , how to create new user uisng Asp.Net Identity?

Comment: Are you using Dependency Injection for your DbContext?

Comment: No , No Dependency Injection

Comment: Do not work like this. Use Dependency Injection. When you have implemented Dependency Injection in your application, then you need to provide a parameter in your class where you implemented CreateNewUser(). Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788272/how-to-instantiate-a-dbcontext-in-ef-core)

Comment: Thanks Vins. I solved the issue.