# Add migration for ApiAuthorizationDbContext from another project - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add migration for `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` from another .NET Core project but cannot instantiate it from design time since I don't know how to get the 2nd parameter `IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions>`.

This is my DbContext constructor (which inherits my custom `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` that accepts TUser, TRole, TKey)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext (DbContextOptions options, IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
        : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }
```

This is my `DesignTimeDbContextFactory`

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<KontestDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options, ????); <--- how to resolve the IOptions<OperationStoreOptions> here ??
    }
}
```

I found an answer from [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13870) but still can not figure out a way how to resolve this param.

I also tried to inject the IOptions<> to the constructor but when add-migration, it throws an exception that the parameterless constructor of DesignTimeDbContextFactory is not found

Can somebody give me a hint through this, I'm quite new to .NET Core / EF Core here and will very much appericiate if someone can help!

(I'm using .NET Core 3.0 and Entity Framework Core)

Answer (score 11):

Create **OperationalStoreOptionsMigrations** inheriting the **IOptions** and pass **OperationalStoreOptionsMigrations** object.
See my answer.

1. Create **OperationalStoreOptionsMigrations** method.

   ```
    public class OperationalStoreOptionsMigrations : 
      IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions>
    {
          public OperationalStoreOptions Value => new OperationalStoreOptions()
          {
                DeviceFlowCodes = new TableConfiguration("DeviceCodes"),
                EnableTokenCleanup = false,
                PersistedGrants = new TableConfiguration("PersistedGrants"),
                TokenCleanupBatchSize = 100,
                TokenCleanupInterval = 3600,
          };
    }
   ```
2. change **DesignTimeDbContextFactory**

   ```
    public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : 
      IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<KontestDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
                IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

                var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var connectionString = 
                    configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

                return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options, new OperationalStoreOptionsMigrations()); 
           }
      }
   ```

Answer (score -3):

Pass your `IOptions<OprerationalStoreOption>` as a parameter in the constructor then you can use it wherever you need to. Then register the `IOptions` service in the`DI` container. Something like this

```
public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args, Options<OperationStoreOptions> optionsBuilder)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()


        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options, optionsBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding it but the CreateDbContext accepts only one argument because the class has to implement CreateDbContext in its interface IDesignTimeDbContextFactory. I also tried to inject the IOptions<> to the constructor but when add-migration, it throws an exception that the parameterless constructor of DesignTimeDbContextFactory is not found.