# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Repository.UnitOfWork'

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

this is my code in .net core 3.1 to implement repository unitofwork and generic.
I write repository,user repository, unitofwork, contex and so.
after run the app there is an error :
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Repository.UnitOfWork'

I dont know what should I pass to the context or unitofwork as 'DbContextOptions'

this is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        UnitOfWork db;
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, UnitOfWork db)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.db = db;
        }
}
```

this is my context:

```
public PandanetContext(DbContextOptions<PandanetContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
```

this is my unit of work:

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        PandanetContext db;
        public UnitOfWork(PandanetContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        public UserRepository UserRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (userRepository == null)
                {
                    userRepository = new UserRepository(db);
                }
                return userRepository;
            }
        }
}
```

this is my Repository:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<UserDomainModel>
    {
        PandanetContext db;
        public UserRepository(PandanetContext context) : base(context)
        {
            db = context;
        }
    }
```

this is actionResult :

```
  public IActionResult Index()
        {            
            UserDomainModel user = new UserDomainModel();
            user.Name = "تست";
            db.UserRepository.create(user);
            db.UserRepository.Save();
            return View();
        }
```

in startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<PandanetContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788272/how-to-instantiate-a-dbcontext-in-ef-core/50788386#50788386

Comment: yes in startup.cs there is @Stefan

Comment: in startup.cs :

services.AddDbContext<PandanetContext>(options =>                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting... can you post the full error?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was mistaken. You need to register the unit of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the `UnitOfWork`:

In your startup.cs you can add the `UnitOfWork` to the services provider:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<UnitOfWork>();
 
    //... etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it works. I'm new in .net core and I am changing my mvc project to .net core. it helped me a lot.