# Automapper Null on Dependency Injection Using [Inject] Attribute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, blazor, nullreferenceexception

I have a class that fetches some data from a database and I then map the data using AutoMapper. However, for some reason, mapper never gets a value injected so I get a NullReferenceException when I try to use mapper.

```cs
public class SearchesEditReview
{
    [Inject]
    public IMapper mapper { get; set; }
        
     public async Task<ViewEvent> GetEditFromId(int id)
     {
        //unrelated code

        return new ViewEvent
                {
                    Data = timelineinfo.FirstOrDefault(),
                    Medias = media,
                    //The below line breaks, saying mapper is null
                    Subjects = mapper.Map<List<DBSubject>, List<ViewSubject>>(subjects)
                };  
     }
}
```

My relevent `Startup.cs` looks like:

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      // Auto Mapper Configurations
      var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
      {
           mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
      });

      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

      IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
      services.AddSingleton(mapper);
}
```

Comment: docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Use  constructor injection. The @inject directive and the Inject attribute can only be used with Razor Components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot Inject into a class like that. The syntax your using would work fine on a `.razor` page however.
Please see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Change your class. Note the constructor.

```
public class SearchesEditReview
{
    public SearchesEditReview(IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
       
    IMapper mapper { get; set; }

    public async Task<ViewEvent> GetEditFromId(int id)
    {
        //unrelated code

        return new ViewEvent
        {
            Data = timelineinfo.FirstOrDefault(),
            Medias = media,
            //The below line breaks, saying mapper is null
            Subjects = mapper.Map<List<DBSubject>, List<ViewSubject>>(subjects)
        };
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`

```
...
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
services.AddSingleton<SearchesEditReview>();
```

Comment: How would I create an instance of ```SearchesEditReview``` with a constructor though?

Comment: @Bubinga Injection works in Controllers , Razor pages, Middleware etc.  In a razor page you can use the [Inject] attribute. In a controller or middleware you simply put injectables in the constructor they will automatically be supplied.

Comment: @Bubinga For example in a `.razor` page if you `[Inject] SearchesEditReview SearchesEditReview` In a controller create a constructor if it doesn't already have one and add SearchesEditReview as a parameter. In my example the injection system will know how to construct it.

Comment: Ahhhh, that make sense. I just tried that and it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets focus on the construction of `SearchesEditReview`, which seems to be unable to correctly bind the automapper property, while it's should be registered correctly.

You are using a binding with an `[Inject]` attribute, but that's not always clear how it works (well at least to me; there are ton's of frameworks, all doing it a little differently). For this reason I tend to use the constructor injection pattern:

```
public class SearchesEditReview
{
     public SearchesEditReview(IMapper mapper) //dependencies here
     {
        //attach to properties
     }
}
```

Next to the downside of don't having a parameter-less constructor, it has 2 advantages:

1. you are forced to pass the parameter, so there will be no ambiguity, it is easier to debug
2. You're independent of the DI framework. Which you'll seldom use.

---

As mentioned, for .net Core you can use a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) for the .net Core Dependency Injection Framework:

```
Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjections:
```

And register like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    //You'll need to pass in the assemblies containing your profiles,
    //or the profiles itself
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(YourProfile1),typeof(YourProfile2)); //etc
}
```

**Note:** The sometimes used loaded assembly scan `GetAssemblies` can be error prone. Since this occurs at startup, profile containing assemblies might not be loaded yet.

See [this blog post](https://www.codewithmukesh.com/blog/automapper-in-aspnet-core/) or [this documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core) for more details.

---

Also keep in mind that you need to make sure the framework is able to construct `SearchesEditReview`.

Comment: No, the mapper is `ServiceLifetime.Transient` in AM.DI for a while now.

Comment: And the `GetAssemblies` stuff is clearly error prone, so most of the times it's easier to simply pass the assemblies that define profiles.

Comment: Good point, I addessed that in the comment, but corrected it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the accepted way to create an instance of that class now that it has a constructor?

Comment: Well, there are several of options: 1) create is manually, using `new` (not really reccommended), 2) create it in your controller, this will work by default: just add the `SearchesEditReview` to the controllers constructor 3) resolve it from the services provider. This should give you some hints, or search for Razor and dependency injection, also see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788272/how-to-instantiate-a-dbcontext-in-ef-core/50788386#50788386